# Is it possible to create a table rows using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html-table

What I am trying to do is retrieve the information passed from a previous page through and display this within a table on another page.

I have currently got the following code:

```
PAGE NAME: EMBELLISHMENT
<script>

 var embellishmentlist_var = embellishment;


 var embellishment_explode = embellishmentlist_var.split("#");



for(var i = 1; i < embellishment_explode.length; i++)
            {

            var embellishment_explode_singleinfo =     embellishment_explode.split("_");

              //var table = '<tr><td>' + embellishment_explode[3] + '</td><td>' + data[7] + '</td><td>' + data[1] + '</td><td>' + data[2] + '</td><td>' + data[4] + '</td><td>' + data[5] + '</td>' + data1 + '<td>' + data[9] + '</td></tr>';
                var table = '<tr><td></td></tr>';
                $('#tableshow > tr').append( table );
                //alert(embellishment_explode[4]);
            }


}

</script>


<html>

 <table>

  <tr id="tableshow">
  </tr>

</table>
```

The foreach can loop round a maximum of 6 times which I hope will create 6 rows within the table however this does not seem to be working. I currently have similar code to the above on another page however the HTML is slightly different. On that page the HTML looks like the following:

```
 PAGE NAME: INFO

<table id="items_table">
  <th>1</th>
  <th>2</th>
    ///etc
</table>
```

The Javascript on that page insert rows into the table. This all works.

Therefore the only difference between the two pages is that on the EMBELLISHMENT page I want to create table rows within a table whereas on the INFO page I am creating the complete table.

Could I please have some assistance even if it is just to say it isn't possible.

Comment: You're trying to append table **rows** to a table **row**. That's not possible. You could only add rows to a table.

Comment: 1. as mentioned by alexP, you add row into row $('tr').parent().append(row) 2. row is not direct child of table - there is tableBody in between $('table > tbody > tr')

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to append table rows to a table row. That's not possible. You could only add rows to a table

**HTML**

```
<table id="tableshow"></table>
```

**JS**

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 6; i++){
    $('#tableshow').append('<tr><td></td></tr>');
}
```